# Python: Image's path as a raw string an input to a function

Tags: python, string, image

Python: I want to get an image as an input from the user as a raw string! I used `input()` to get the path. Giving it as a raw string makes the program work, I can do it by appending r before the path, but `Image.open(' ')` also takes `r` as a string and producing an error. Can someone help me in resolving this problem.

```
path=input('Please enter the path of the image')
im=Image.open(path)
```

get an error as no file found

if i give..

```
y='r'+path
im=Image.open(y)
```

then the error is

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'rC:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\.......jpeg'
```

I am new to python, so please help me if there is any method by which I can solve this issue.

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: 3.7 is the version and spyder is the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raw strings are for a programmer's convenience; you don't have to have your users enter raw strings as normal input.

See the end of this post for the solution to your problem. Because you said you are new to Python, I have decided to give a detailed answer here.

### Why raw strings?

Normal strings assign special meaning to the `\` (backslash) character. This is fine as `\` can be escaped by using `\\` (two backslashes) to represent a single backslash.

However, this can sometimes become ugly.

Consider, for example, a path: `C:\Users\Abhishek\test.txt`. To represent this as a normal string in Python, all `\` must be escaped:

```
string = 'C:\\Users\\Abhishek\\test.txt'
```

You can avoid this by using raw strings. Raw strings don't treat `\` specially.

```
string = r'C:\Users\Abhishek\test.txt'
```

That's it. This is the only use of raw strings, viz., convenience.

### Solution

If you are using Python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. If you are using Python 3 (as you should be) `input` is fine. **Don't try to input the path as a raw string.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Abhishek. But..path is a string. it should be a raw string, only then i can open the image, otherwise i can't open the image. I am getting an error when i don't give the path as a raw string. and i can't add r within ' ' in open command. thats the problem here

Comment: @Chandu Did you try out my suggestion? No where else can I find a statement that only a raw string can be used as a path for a file to be opened. P.S.: I hope you are not confusing raw strings with binary files (the `'b'` mode passed to `open` function).

Comment: I tried, but it didn|t work out. I can't open the path.

Comment: @Chandu can you tell me what went wrong? Reference a Gist if possible.

Comment: @its working abhishek. I have entered the path as a normal string and its working. don't know why it didn't work these many days, until I append r. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chandu If it has worked you can accept my answer by clicking on the tick. I would appreciate that. Cheers!